# Common Geometric Series with Euler's Constant

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a common infinite sum that would explain the following equivalency:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ke^{-k}=\frac{e^{-1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}$, and likewise

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ke^{-k-1}=\frac{e^{-2}}{(1-e^{-2})^2}$

Comment: Looks like derivative of geometric series at $x=1/e$.

Comment: These two sums are the same with the only difference of a comon factor. Moreover, the second equality is not correct

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that for $|x|<1$ one can write.
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k$$
We can differentiate this to get
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$
and multiplying by $x$ gives
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k}$$
Use this with $x=e^{-1}(<1)$ to get the first sum. The second is actually not correct, which can be seen by plugging $e^{-1}$ into $f'$.

Comment: Thank you, I see how the second one is incorrect. Re-checking the solution to the problem I have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ke^{-k-1}=\frac{e^{-2}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}$, which is different. However, based on the equivalencies you showed me, I don't understand how they arrived at this either.To me $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}ke^{-k-1}$ should be $=\frac{1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}$.I can't understand where the $e^{-2}$ in the numerator comes from...

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet Multiply both sides of the first one by $e^{-1}$ -- you should get the second.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize but this algebra is very confusing to me, but I think I am almost there. If I am applying what you are saying within the framework provided by @OnlyDay, Am I understanding your suggestion correctly if applied thusly:  $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}kx^{k+1}=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}$   and so if x=$e^{-1}$ we have $\frac{({e^{-1}})^2}{(1-e^{-1})^2}$.

Comment: Yup, you've got it!